# Thyristor leaking AC? Reading thyristor code?

Tags: batteries, charger, thyristor

1. I'm refurbishing an automotive battery charger. It uses a full-wave rectifier in combination with a thyristor (which I think is acting as output cutoff). The charger output has is the correct DC voltage, but it has an unusually high AC reading (>3V AC in 12V charge mode, >4V AC in 12V charge mode). The rectifier section has ~1V AC output (typical in the other chargers I've tested), so the AC is coming from the thyristor. Is this abnormal behavior?
2. How do I properly interpret this thyristor code:

BTW69200NS
7SAFW VU
PHL 7S 232

I'm able to decode the first line, aside from the "S." What's conveyed in the second and third lines?

Comment: Car battery chargers DC but without smoothing capacitors and some voltmeters read this as 4VAC.

Comment: have you googled the thyristor codes?

Comment: @schnedan Yep, Googled, tried Digikey, searched here and a number of other sites. I can find parts that match the first line, but not the latter two. I'm unsure if they're relevant, hence the question.

Comment: I found a datasheet from ST... is there a manufacturer symbol on your device? can you post a photo?

Comment: @schnedan Thanks for the reply. Prompted by your question, I changed my camera setup and was able to capture images of the markings (challenging for this chip). Indeed, it does appear to be an ST.
[BTW69-200NS image](https://www.reddit.com/user/BizzEB/comments/j2bj4m/st_btw69200ns/).

I had found this [ST datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/btw69-1200n.pdf), but I don't see where it mentions the "S" or the second and third lines. Given the manufacturer confirmation, I'll just ply them for information and post what I learn here for posterity.

Comment: *How are you measuring the "AC"?*Likely, you are detecting pulsating DC, which many meters will show as if it's true AC.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Hmmm... that's very interesting. I'll have to find a way to better examine the output. I was using a simple Fluke multimeter. I'll see if the local makerspace has an oscilloscope. Do you think the thyristor functioning as a PWM control? or?

Comment: @Eeight with your new info I can find pictures... well its a ST but the logo on your pictures looks different from the original...or? https://images.app.goo.gl/ETqxMsbSivGRBHBy5  https://images.app.goo.gl/JmgTrAv6uEiR9SNL8

Comment: @schnedan My part looks very much like the first you linked. I've seen a few of these for sale, but the second and third lines are slightly different. I'm unsure of their meaning or relevance.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I'm picking up a Digilent Analog Discovery 2 so I can get a better look at that output. Thanks for the tip!